# Expo splash screen appear, but the app doesn't start

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, expo-router

When I open the app using Expo Go or a Development Build, I see the splash screen, but then nothing happens. After waiting for a few minutes, I tried stopping the server by pressing `Ctrl + c`, and I received an error message as shown below. However, after 1-2 seconds, the following error showed and the app suddenly closed.

I created the development build using the following commands:

```
$ npx expo prebuild --clean --yarn
$ npx expo run:android --variant debug
```

It's worth mentioning that everything works perfectly fine in the Android release build and the web build!

[image]

I'm using:

- Expo SDK 49
- expo-router 2.0.0
- @react-navigation/drawer 6.6.4
- react-native-reanimated 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I ran `yarn add @expo/metro-config` then change my `metro.config.js` with:

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.resolverMainFields.unshift("sbmodern");
defaultConfig.resolver.sourceExts.push("cjs");
defaultConfig.resolver.sourceExts.push("mjs");

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

And then rebuild the project with `npx expo run:android --variant debug`